# dygraph equivalent for highcharts area range charts

Tags: javascript, highcharts, dygraphs

I prefer dygraphs over highchart graphs as interative javascript graphs, so I was wondering is there a dygraph equivalent for the highcharts area range graphs (http://www.highcharts.com/demo/arearange) as is suggested in the link?

I have looked through the examples and documentation here (http://dygraphs.com/), but not sure I can see anything that fits this.

As always any help here would be much appreciated.

Kindest regards,

HLM

Answer (score 1):

I was originally using R to do this...and have implemented a version that carries out the range

```
# range areas...
library(quantmod)
library(dygraphs)

getSymbols(c("MSFT", "HPQ"), from = "2014-06-01", auto.assign=TRUE)

stocks <- cbind(MSFT[,"MSFT.Close"]-10,HPQ[,"HPQ.Close"])
colnames(stocks) <- c('A','B')

stocks$A_low <- NA
stocks$B_low <- NA

stocks$A_high <- stocks$A
stocks$B_high <- stocks$B

stocks[stocks$A>stocks$B,'B_low'] <- stocks[stocks$A>stocks$B,'B']
stocks[stocks$A>stocks$B,'A_low'] <- stocks[stocks$A>stocks$B,'B']

stocks[stocks$A<stocks$B,'B_low'] <- stocks[stocks$A<stocks$B,'A']
stocks[stocks$A<stocks$B,'A_low'] <- stocks[stocks$A<stocks$B,'A']


dygraph(stocks, main = "A vs B Share Prices") %>% 
  dySeries(c("A_low", "A", "A_high"), label = "A") %>%
  dySeries(c("B_low", "B", "B_high"), label = "B")
```

Answer (score 0):

The bottom chart on the [SF vs. NY temperatures](http://dygraphs.com/tests/temperature-sf-ny.html) example does something like this. You want to use [customBars](http://dygraphs.com/data.html).